# Callback is no more accepting in Model.InsertMany() after version 7.0.0 update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hii guys I have currently working on a project where I am using mongoose and my I have latest version of 7.0.0.
The issue is that when I am trying to give a callback in Model.insertMany() operation in console its showing that
** MongooseError: Model.insertMany() no longer accepts a callback**

I added my code below. I want that is there any other alternatives  to solve this error.

in app.js ----

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");// require mongoose
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

//create a todolistDB database and connect it
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/todolistDB", {useNewUrlParser:true});

//create a Schema of only name feild
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     name:String
});

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema); // create a model of Items

const Item1= new Item({
  name:"Welcome to the todolist"
});

const Item2= new Item({
  name:"Click + button to add items"
});

const Item3= new Item({
  name:"click delete to remove item"
});

const defaultItem= [Item1, Item2, Item3 ]; // create a array of items doc

Item.insertMany(defaultItem,{
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    console.log("Items added succesfully");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function that formally accompanied the insertMany() method has been deprecated (no longer in use).

But you can use this instead;

```
Item.insertMany(defultItems).then(function () {
    console.log("Successfully saved defult items to DB");
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Note how the "then" and "catch" functions are continuous and a part of the "insertMany" method, as they are all joined using the dot (.) notation

Comment: Yes, I appreciate your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

```
Item.insertMany(defultItems)
      .then(function () {
        console.log("Successfully saved defult items to DB");
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try use await to handle the promise.

[MDN Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Here's a quick sample of how to use await. You probably might experience an issue with unable to handle async with the following code below if you just copy directly

```
await Item.insertMany(defaultItem).then(
  (result) => {
     console.log("Items added succesfully");
  }
).catch(
  (err) => {
     console.log(err);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback function that formally accompanied the insertMany() method has been deprecated (no longer in use).

But you can use this instead;

```
Item.insertMany(defaultItems).then(function () {
   console.log("Successfully saved default items to DB");
}).catch(function (err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

for example I've used this;

```
Fruit.insertMany([kiwi,orange,banana]).then(function(){
    console.log("Success");
}).catch(function (err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too I think,

```
const insertItems = async function () {
  try {
    const response = await Item.insertMany(defaultItem);
    console.log(response);
    console.log("Items added succesfully");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

insertItems();
```

Comment: please add description to the code

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.insertMany([item1,item2])
.then(function(){
console.log("Successfully Inserted");
})
.catch(function(err){
console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**